# How to make SelectMany without argument work for generic IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, generic-type-argument

I am trying to create a `SelectMany()` extension that can work without any query selector (so no argument at all). I have come up with the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<V> SelectMany<T, V>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) where T : IEnumerable<V> {
    return enumerable.SelectMany(e => e);
}
```

But the type arguments aren't recognized when I try to call it like this:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, List<decimal>>();
var values = d.Values.SelectMany();
```

> The type arguments for method 'CollectionsExtensions.SelectMany(IEmumerable' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying
>   the type arguments explicitly.

It only works with:

```
public static IEnumerable<V> SelectMany<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, List<V>>.ValueCollection enumerable) {
    return enumerable.SelectMany(e => e);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're not giving it a type for `V`.

Comment: so weird that   T is IEnumerable of V !

Comment: `var values = d.Values.SelectMany<List<decimal>, decimal>()`

Comment: @DavidG the question is actually why can't the types be inferred?

Comment: @ErwinMayer What's it going to use to infer V? There's nothing between the parens to infer it from. Your `ValueCollection` overload works because you found a way to put all the type params in between the parens. But as dynamoid shows, you don't need `V` and `IEnumerable<V>` to be separate type parameters. The only type that needs to be parameterized is `decimal`. Everything else is an ienumerable of it, or an ienumerable of those.

Comment: I also wanted to write such an extension method. In the end, however, I wrote my code using LINQ queries, using multiple from clauses. This seemed more readable to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LINQ's `SelectMany` method expects a selector function that provides an `IEnumerable<V>` from an *arbitrary* object.

You want your `SelectMany` method to process an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<V>>` object instead, so there is no need to specify the selector function.

So keep it simple:

```
static IEnumerable<T> SelectMany<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> enumerable)
    => enumerable.SelectMany(e => e);
```

Comment: It works! I I wonder why the method with more complex type specifications doesn't work, but at least this solves my problem.

Comment: @ErwinMayer, the automatic type inference doesn't work in your example because the compiler can only infer the generic parameter types from the parameters, not from the type constraints.